# Windows XP invalid certificate on Nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate

I migrated my SSL websites and certificates from Apache to Nginx and from that moment all Windows XP clients does not recognize the SSL certificate (it is a wildcard certificate issued by Trustico).

The old configuration on previous Apache servers was this:

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/*_mysite.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/*_mysite.com.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/*_mysite.com.ca-bundle
```

And the new configuration on Nginx servers is this:

```
ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/*_mysite.com.crt
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/*_mysite.com.key;
ssl_session_timeout 5m;
ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
ssl_ciphers ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv3:+EXP;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
```

Nginx does not support the SSLCertificateChainFile parameter, so I read that I need to append the *_mysite.com.ca-bundle file below the *_mysite.com.crt one.

After this, other operating system than Windows XP are working good, but Windows XP is still recognizing a wrong certificate (it returns the "certificate error" message).

I cannot solve this problem, could you help me please?

Comment: You can't use Internet Explorer on Windows XP anymore, and nobody should be using Windows XP at all anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> other operating system than Windows XP are working good, but Windows XP is still recognizing a wrong certificate..

In this case your setup requires [Server Name Indication (SNI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) and somewhere you have configured another certificate for clients not able to do SNI, like MSIE8 on XP.

Comment: Thank you very much Steffen! The problem was that I weren't seeing the second certificate on the same IP address! Bye!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that IE8 and older on Windows XP does not support SNI. If you need to support users on Win XP/IE 8, each site needs its own dedicated IP address and corresponding SSL certificate.